# Required field and regular expression validators for the bound field elements inside the grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my gridview and I have added a command field  **Edit** which will enable to edit the particular values in the grid view.The code is working fine.i just need to know how to add a required field validator and regular expression validator  for  the bound field.
As far as I know adding a textbox inside item template and then validating using **ControlToValidate =”id”** is possible,but is there any chances of adding required field validator for **Bound Field**

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
        style="top: 538px; left: 216px; position: absolute; height: 133px; width: 534px" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
        Visible="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr.No.">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblserial" runat="server">
                        </asp:Label>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FID" HeaderText="Faculty ID" ReadOnly="true"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="FID" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString ="{0:d}" SortExpression="Date" ReadOnly="true"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Theme" HeaderText="Theme" SortExpression="Theme" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Duration" HeaderText="Duration" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                SortExpression="Duration" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Organizer" HeaderText="Role" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                SortExpression="Organizer" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>


             <asp:BoundField DataField="Venue" HeaderText="Venue" SortExpression="Venue" ReadOnly="true"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateDate" HeaderText="UpdateDate"  DataFormatString ="{0:d}" ReadOnly="true"
                SortExpression="UpdateDate" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
         <EmptyDataTemplate><h3 align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large">No Records Found</h3></EmptyDataTemplate>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [WorkshopSC_det] WHERE ([FID] = @FID)"
       UpdateCommand="UPDATE [WorkshopSC_det] SET Duration=@Duration,Organizer=@Organizer WHERE(Theme=@Theme) ">

        <SelectParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="FID" SessionField="FID" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Theme"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Duration" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Organizer" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Role" />


        </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Hope this may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685853/how-to-give-required-field-validator-to-textbox-in-gridview

Comment: And this one - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203892/Required-BoundField-in-Gridview

Comment: i am not using item template and textbox,I need to add RFV for the bound field itself

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Bound fields and as per my understanding bound fields are not supported for field validators.
**I tried two solutions.**

1. I followed **[this article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Required-BoundField-Validate-BoundField-TextBox-in--Mode-of-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)** and it worked.But in my case I wanted to add regex and required field validators and this approach is not consistent when there are more than one validator.

But you can try it.

2. **Replace bound fields with Template fields and add item templates and field validator inside the template field as below**. It is for the faculty ID field and you can repeat the same for other columns.

The other advantage of Template fields is it allows you to add footer and header rows to the column which might be handy in case of row insertion to the grid.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Faculty ID" SortExpression="FID"   ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="fidText" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("FID") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValidatorId"  runat="server" ControlToValidate="fidText" Display="Dynamic"  ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Value is required."> * </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="fidText" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid value" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="YOUR REGEX EXPRESSION">Enter a valid value for Faculty Id.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```